# How to profile benchmarks using the pprof tool?

Tags: go, profiling, benchmarking, pprof

I want to **profile** my benchmarks generated by `go test -c`, but the `go tool pprof` needs a profile file usually generated inside the main function like [this](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs):

```
func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    if *cpuprofile != "" {
        f, err := os.Create(*cpuprofile)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        pprof.StartCPUProfile(f)
        defer pprof.StopCPUProfile()
    }
```

How can I create a profile file within my benchmarks ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As described in https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Testing_flags you can specify the profile file using the flag `-cpuprofile`.

For example

```
go test -cpuprofile cpu.out
```

Comment: an additional piece that was not at first obvious to me is that a <package name>.test file is created for you to pass to pprof

Answer (score 3):

Use the `-cpuprofile` flag to `go test` as documented at http://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_testing_flags

Answer (score 2):

This post explains how to profile benchmarks with an example: [Benchmark Profiling with pprof](https://stackimpact.com/blog/benchmark-profiling-with-pprof/).

The following benchmark simulates some CPU work.

```
package main

import (
    "math/rand"
    "testing"
)

func BenchmarkRand(b *testing.B) {
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        rand.Int63()
    }
}
```

To generate a CPU profile for the benchmark test, run:

```
go test -bench=BenchmarkRand -benchmem -cpuprofile profile.out
```

The `-memprofile` and `-blockprofile` flags can be used to generate memory allocation and blocking call profiles.

To analyze the profile use the Go tool:

```
go tool pprof profile.out
(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 1.16s, 100% of 1.16s total
Showing top 10 nodes out of 22
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
     0.41s 35.34% 35.34%      0.41s 35.34%  sync.(*Mutex).Unlock
     0.37s 31.90% 67.24%      0.37s 31.90%  sync.(*Mutex).Lock
     0.12s 10.34% 77.59%      1.03s 88.79%  math/rand.(*lockedSource).Int63
     0.08s  6.90% 84.48%      0.08s  6.90%  math/rand.(*rngSource).Uint64 (inline)
     0.06s  5.17% 89.66%      1.11s 95.69%  math/rand.Int63
     0.05s  4.31% 93.97%      0.13s 11.21%  math/rand.(*rngSource).Int63
     0.04s  3.45% 97.41%      1.15s 99.14%  benchtest.BenchmarkRand
     0.02s  1.72% 99.14%      1.05s 90.52%  math/rand.(*Rand).Int63
     0.01s  0.86%   100%      0.01s  0.86%  runtime.futex
         0     0%   100%      0.01s  0.86%  runtime.allocm
```

The bottleneck in this case is the mutex, caused by the default source in math/rand being synchronized.

Other profile presentations and output formats are also possible, e.g. `tree`. Type `help` for more options.

Note, that any initialization code before the benchmark loop will also be profiled.